# How do I select the 3 columns with highest values from a row in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 6, 6 ,3 ,4], [7, 2, 9, 9, 2, 7]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'a_select','b_select','c_select'])

df
```

Now, I may need to reorganize the dataframe (or use two) to accomplish this, but...

I'd like to select the 2 largest values from each '_select' column per row, then use that to mean the corresponding column.

For example, row 1 would mean the values from a & b, row 2 a & c (NOT the values from the _select columns that we're looking at).

Currently I'm just iterating each row - as that seems rather simple, but slow with a large dataset - however I can't figure out how to use an apply or lambda function to do the equivelant (or if it's even possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple oneliner using [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```
>>> df.filter(like='select').apply(lambda s: s.nlargest(2), 1).mean(1)
```

For performance, maybe `numpy` is useful:

```
>>> np.sort(df.filter(like='select').to_numpy(), 1)[:, -2:].mean(1)
```

To get values from the first columns, use `argsort`

```
>>> arr = df.filter(like='select').to_numpy()
>>> df[['a', 'b', 'c']].to_numpy()[[[x] for x in np.arange(len(arr))], 
np.argsort(arr, 1)][:, -2:].mean(1)
```

---

```
array([1.5, 5. , 8. ])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However (and this is the confusing part), I was hoping to use the referenced _select columns to pick the values from the similarly named columns *without* select.

So if "a_select" and "b_select" have the highest values, I actually want to mean the values from "a" and "b" somehow.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still trying to wrap my head around how exactly this works, but I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a name for the method you use to run a function on the numpy array? I mean the [x] for x ..., np.argsort...  I haven't seen that before and would like to learn more. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Yes! That's called indexing and slicing in numpy. There's some examples in the docs : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html